# jQuery mask not adding characters

Tags: jquery, .net, model-view-controller, mask

I'm trying to use the plugin jquery mask, but it doesn't work very well.

Basically, when I put the mask on, it limits the input and shows the placeholder, but it doesn't add the characters like  "." and "-".

[input with placeholder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hrxa.png)

[input filled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2mxn.png)

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CPF, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CPF, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" , id="txtCPF", @type="text"} })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CPF, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

<script src="~/js/jquery.mask.js"></script>


<script>
    $('#txtCPF').mask('000.000.000-00', { placeholder: "___.___.___-__" });
</script>
```

I want to know what's happening. The browser recognizes the plugin but it is not working.

Comment: Have you checked if there is any error message in browser?

Comment: yes, the console shows this error: "el.off is not a function"